# python 2枚の画像の誤差計算について

Tags: python, python3

画像内で指定した領域に平均フィルタをかけて、フィルタをかける前の画像との誤差を画素ごとの画素値の差で求め、それが最大になる場合と最小になる場合の領域の位置と処理後の画像を求めようとしています。
誤差は処理前後の画像のrgb値の差の二乗を求め、それらの合計によって定義します。

以下のように誤差計算の動作確認を行ったところ、動作が非常に重く作業が進行しません。
問題点や解決法をご教示いただけると幸いです。

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


def main():
    F = cv2.imread("gazou.jpg")
    m, n, c = F.shape
    h = 30
    M = math.floor(m/h)
    N = math.floor(n/h)
    im = F[1:M*h, 1:N*h]
    list = []
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(h):
            D = im[i:(i+(M-1)*h-1), j:(j+(N-1)*h-1)]
            P = cv2.blur(D, (h, h))
            List = []
            for x in range((M-1)*h-1):
                for y in range((N-1)*h-1):
                    Db,Dg,Dr = D[x,y]
                    Pb,Pg,Pr = P[x,y]
                    e = pow(int(Dr)-int(Pr), 2)+pow(int(Dg)-int(Pg), 2)+pow(int(Db)-int(Pb), 2)
                    List.append(e)
            E = sum(List)
            list.append(E)
    Emin = min(list)
    Emax = max(list)
    print(Emin)
    print(Emax)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: metropolisさん、ご返信ありがとうございます。returnについてよく理解ができていませんでした。
実はreturnを付けていない場合も試していたのですが、ものすごく処理が重く、原因も分かりませんでした。
もし間違えている部分などありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 説明の文言からすると、もしかしてこの辺が関連していますか？ [OpenCVで平均２乗誤差を計算する](https://iwaki2009.blogspot.com/2013/02/opencv_12.html), [OpenCV&Pythonで画像の類似度を計算させる〜イケメンの顔比較](http://kamonohashiperry.com/archives/699), [画質評価アラカルト　～SSIMってすごい！～](https://dftalk.jp/?p=18111), [How-To: Python Compare Two Images](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/)

Answer (score 1):

やはり四重ループが気になりますね．NumPy自体はC言語等で実装されているため，ある程度速いはずなのですが，for文を書いてしまうとその性能を発揮できず，どうして遅くなってしまいます．

とりあえず，内側のfor文2つは簡単に無くせるので書き換えると以下のようになりました．

```py
def main2():
    F = cv2.imread("gazou.jpg")
    m, n, c = F.shape
    h = 30
    M = math.floor(m/h)
    N = math.floor(n/h)
    im = F[1:M*h, 1:N*h]
    list = []
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(h):
            D = im[i:(i+(M-1)*h-1), j:(j+(N-1)*h-1)]
            P = cv2.blur(D, (h, h))
            E = ((D.astype(np.int) - P.astype(np.int))**2).sum()
            list.append(E)
    Emin = min(list)
    Emax = max(list)
    print(Emin)
    print(Emax)
```

手元で256x256の画像を入力に `%time` で速度を測ったところ，元コードが

```
CPU times: user 1min 26s, sys: 56 ms, total: 1min 27s
Wall time: 1min 27s
```

であったところ，`main2`への変更で

```
CPU times: user 346 ms, sys: 4 µs, total: 346 ms
Wall time: 345 ms
```

になりました（出力の一致は1ケースだけですが確認しています）．

---

思考の流れとしては，

```py
for x in range((M-1)*h-1):
    for y in range((N-1)*h-1):
        Db,Dg,Dr = D[x,y]
        Pb,Pg,Pr = P[x,y]
        e = pow(int(Dr)-int(Pr), 2)+pow(int(Dg)-int(Pg), 2)+pow(int(Db)-int(Pb), 2)
        List.append(e)
E = sum(List)
```

を一旦

```py
for x in range((M-1)*h-1):
    for y in range((N-1)*h-1):
        for c in range(3):
            e = pow(int(D[x, y, c])-int(P[x, y, c]), 2)
            List.append(e)
E = sum(List)  # sumを取るので辻褄は合う
```

の様に思うと，`List`を `(D.astype(np.int) - P.astype(np.int))**2` に置き換えれば，for文を無くせることに気がつくという感じですね．

---

NumPyを使っているときは，NumPy配列に対するfor文をいかに減らせるかが，速いコードを書くための一つの大きな指標になるはずです．

Comment: 皆様、ご返信とご回答ありがとうございました。
アカウントは違いますが質問者です。
信用度が足りていないため回答にて失礼いたします。 ご指摘の通りfor文を減らすと格段に早い処理ができました。
大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: [こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できますのでお試しくださいませ。質問者のアカウントであれば回答を承認することができます。